# NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python, and I want to write a csv file, that lists the roots of my equation.
I am working on Sage.
My code is  :

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    c.writerows(root)
```

The error I am getting is " NameError: name 'csv' is not defined "

Can anybody help please?

Comment: you need to do `import csv` first

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is not a builtin, although it's part of the standard library. You need to *import* it:

```
import csv

# your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error using this code:

`from csv import QUOTE_MINIMAL, DictWriter`

Then I edited the code to:

> import csv

now it works perfectly fine for me. I am using python3.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Hey @ann jenny, kudos for making this question more helpful by including other reasons people might get the NameError.  I'd suggest updating your answer to show why it's unique.  In your case, you were only importing part of the .csv library, and attempting to use parts you hadn't imported was causing the error.